# How to create drop down in Magento

Tags: magento

I am new on Magento. I want to create a dropdown for menu in Magento. When we take mouse oven main menu it will show drop down that display sub menu.

Header navigation manage by `top.phtml`

`location:app/design/frontend/default/shalu_theme/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml`

In header it shows three main category and also showing sub category on frontend. In admin I am having three main category given below

`Admin->Catalog->Select Manage Category`

```
      CATEGORY:
              Furniture(6)
              Electronics(42)
              Apparel(66)
```

I want to create a drop down menu mean that these three `main category` as a main header navigation. And sub category should be shown in drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Well ofcorse this is possible, but it isn't really a "Magento" thing to show a "dropdown" menu.

By default Magento is showing a tree in the `'page/html/header.phtml'` where `$this->getchild('topmenu')` is loaded. From there you can play with CSS/JS to make it a dropdown menu you wish.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code

```
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('name', 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('name') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
Name A-Z
</option>

<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('name', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('name') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
Name Z-A
</option>

<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('price', 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
Price - Low to High
</option>

<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('price', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
Price - High to Low
</option>

<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('entity_id', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('entity_id') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
Newest Products
</option>

<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('entity_id', 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('entity_id') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
Oldest Products
</option>
```